# sending data from one view to another view with a button

Tags: android, android-view

I have a button that is the last element inside a tablerow, like this:

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/person1_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:tag="@drawable/profile_one"
    android:src="@drawable/profile_one"
    />
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/person1_seek"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/person1_name"
                android:hint="@string/person1_name" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="ShowView" />
</TableRow>
```

The code for the button looks like this:

```
public void ShowView(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplaySeekAgain.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

When the button is pressed, I need to send data from this layout, to the new layout, specifically this data:

> android:text="@string/person1_name"

from one of the TextViews

and this:

> android:src="@drawable/profile_one"

from the ImageView.

I tried using a tag in the button code for the name like this:

```
   String text_tag = view.getTag().toString();
   intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME, text_tag);
```

And that does work, but I can't figure out how to also send the image from the ImageView.

Is there a way to send both?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the drawable id as a tag as well on the image view and send it as an extra through the intent to the other Activity.

```
public void ShowView(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplaySeekAgain.class);
    int drawableId = (Integer) myImageView.getTag();
    String textTag = (String) view.getTag();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME, text_tag);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DRAWABLE_ID, drawableId);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: how do I pass in the image view, in your example, myImageView?  thanks

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell The imageView should be a Global variable and you should init it on the onCreate() after `setContentView()`   `myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.person1_icon);`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the image you're talking about is not a drawable resource, just as you're passing the `String` as extras, you can pass an Image (Bitmap) too. So, get a `Bitmap` from your `ImageView` like this:

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
```

Since `Bitmap` implements Parcelable, you can put it in extras like

```
intent.putExtra(IMAGEVIEW_TAG, bitmap)
```

Just an advice, if the `Bitmap` is too large you'll start running into `TransactionTooLarge` exceptions especially if you target [API level 25](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#other) (Android N devices). You would want to consider storing the image into a DB or another approach that doesn't involve passing around large objects like creating a singleton class that holds on to the objects.

If it's a drawable resource, you can refer to Ahmed's answer.